# Can't fix "stream or file could not be opened" in Docker/Laravel environment

Tags: laravel, docker, file-permissions

I am trying to configure a Docker container to run a Laravel project.  I have been beating my head against problem after problem, and each time I solve one another one comes up within seconds.  The current problem is that every time I try to access the Laravel container through the Docker dashboard "view in browser" option, I get this error:

The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4.1-apache

USER root

WORKDIR ../code

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
        unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete
    
COPY ./.docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html 
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

My Docker-compose file is:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: 'project'
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'project_database'
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
```

I have tried every solution previously posted here for this issue, and none of them have worked.  I can't even be sure I'm applying the solutions correctly because I am a beginner at Docker and a beginner at Linux and the numerous layers of settings and parameters that are required to make Docker work might as well be written in hieroglyphics for all the sense I can make of them.  I am not even sure if the error is talking about a folder on my desktop computer or a folder within the container.

Comment: Does the specified file exist? What are the permissions on it? Perhaps you might be better off not trying to use Docker. There are a number of easy-to-install packages that include a web server and database. Also note that PHP 7.4 and MySQL 5.7 are both very old and unsupported at this point. And, allowing ownership of every file by the web server is unsafe, since the owner can write to these files.

Comment: Valid point on the versions; I've changed the version of PHP to be 8.1, and MySQL to "latest".  If I remove the chown line for the storage folder so the build succeeds, and run the resulting container, then yes, there is a folder /var/www/html/storage/logs, and it does contain the file laravel.log.  ls -l gives me: "-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1320 Mar 10 19:45 laravel.log".  As for why use Docker, my coworker and I want to have identical dev environments on all computers: desktop PCs for the office and laptops for working remotely.  I thought Docker could provide that.

Comment: Well if the log file is owned by root, it seems like something has gone wrong with your ownership changes...

Comment: Actually, it doesn't look like you're creating your Laravel directory in the docker file. If you're doing it afterwards as root, obviously setting the permissions beforehand won't do anything. **After** you create your Laravel project, try running `chown -R www-data /var/www/html/your_project_dir/storage`

Comment: You do not want www-data to own other files outside the storage directory. Consider www-data as "everyone in the world" since it's what your web server is running as, and it's exposed to the world. Do you want everyone in the world to be able to modify your app code or access your `.env` file? Probably not.

Comment: One last note, if you're set on Docker, why not use Laravel's own image? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail

Comment: @miken32: Thanks for all of the advice/ideas.  Why not use Sail?  Well, honestly, I don't know.  We're trying to convert an existing project to run in Docker containers, but I've had atrocious luck in finding a container image that will work at all.  Every one I try eventually winds up with an error I can't solve - even when using new installs of Laravel and Docker on a factory-new laptop.  Do you (or anyone) know of a Laravel/Docker tutorial that is simple, easy to follow, and 100% foolproof?

Comment: I don't use Docker, I just install a web server and database on my dev machine, since it's easier than having a separate staging server. If your PHP and Laravel versions match, that's 99% of having "identical" environments. I develop on Mac and deploy to Linux, very very rarely has it caused issues.